# Character encoding php mysql

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf8-decode

I have a table where the data are stored like `boÃ®tes` with none utf8 characters. Now I have my php script which works fine on my local machine.

```
$utf = utf8_decode($details);
echo "UTF8-DE : ".$utf."<hr>";-> `boîtes`
```

When I put this script on another machine its not working  its echoing `boÃ®tes` . I am sure it depends on the charset of the php or server? Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `set_charset` function

#### For mySqli

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
```

#### For mySql

```
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $connection);
```

#### Alternative

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Set it up with headers

`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`